# strange java string array null pointer exception

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception

This problem came up in a practice test:  create a new string array, initialize it to null, then initializing the first element and printing it.  Why does this result in a null pointer exception?  Why doesn't it print "one"?   Is it something to do with string immutability?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String arr[] = new String[10];
            arr = null;
            arr[0] = "one";
            System.out.print(arr[0]);
        } catch(NullPointerException nex) { 
            System.out.print("null pointer exception"); 
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.print("exception");
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You set `arr` to `null`. What else could possibly happen when you try to access an element of `arr`?

Comment: Should I downvote this question? >:)

Comment: `arr` is a `String[]` variable.  If you set `arr` to null then you are setting the `String[]` to null -- the initial `new String[10]` is gone.  Then setting `arr[0]` tries to use a null array reference.  You could set `arr[0]` to be null and then set it to be `"one"` but not the `arr` array.

Comment: Think of it as null[0] = "one". `arr` is no longer referencing ("pointing at", sort of) the space that could hold up to ten `String`s.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you made `arr` referring to `null`, so it threw a `NullPointerException`.

**EDIT:**

Let me explain it via figures:

After this line:

```
String arr[] = new String[10];
```

10 places will be reserved in the heap for the array `arr`:

[image]

and after this line:

```
arr = null;
```

You are removing the reference to the array and make it refer to `null`:

[image]

So when you call this line:

```
arr[0] = "one";
```

A `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Comment: I know I set arr reference to null, but then I changed it.    Are you saying once the arr reference is null it can never be changed?

Comment: no, it has nothing to do with changable or not, you just can not put something into a `null`.

Comment: Picture is worth a thousand words +1

Comment: That _IS_ a nice picture -- should be copyrighted or something.  Thanks!

Comment: @Pregnantmom You are welcome. Don't forget to accept this answer if you find it solves your problrm :)

Answer (score 1):

With `arr = null;` you are deleting the reference to the object.
So you can't access it anymore with `arr[anynumber]` .

Answer (score 0):

`arr is null`, and then... if it did print `one`, wouldn't you be surprised? put a string into a null?

Comment: arr[0] is not null.  I'm printing arr[0].  Why do you think arr[0] is null?

Comment: arr is null, your exception is thrown from `arr[0] = "one";` **NOT** `System.out.print(arr[0]);` you can not put something into a `null`.